# Hadoop Mapper Reducer Taking So much Time

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MR code for small files its taking 7 minutes for 15gb single file.
But for multiple file of 37gb its taking too much time and showing percentage 1% completed in 1 minute consistently.
Please suggest me.

Comment: You need to show the code to get a realistic response to this. It will be likely flagged or deleted otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake I put custom logger in the code so every time when MR run it was logging in MR log file that's why it was taking time.

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce was never designed for low latency. The idea of MapReduce is that you have cases where you process all the data in parallel. The key idea was to reduce the time by parallelism.

Take wordcount for example. Lets say, you want to run a wordcount on 50 GB. Running this on a single machine, might take long. Paralleling it to lets say 10 machines means 5 GB per machine in parallel. Thats an improvement. This are the cases what MapReduce is designed for.

If you looking for a technology that returns result fasts and also does this with random reads, consider a different technology. Depending on your specific needs, there are several approaches that might solve your problem better.